# Good Books on the history of Zero

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, mathematics-education, books

I am looking for books that discuss the origins of the zero, specifically the differences in the use and concept of  the zero number among different civilizations (considering also the Mesoamerican cultures).

Comment: Not sure why this got a down-vote. Seems like a reasonable specific reference-request to me.

Comment: Here is one: "Zero: The Biography of a Dangerous Idea". Indeed, for your inquiry, it was just much easier to search the web than looking for an answer here.

Comment: @quid I didn't down-vote. But I can imagine why. Just a 5 minutes search on the web will come up with an answer.

Comment: Here is a review to the book I introduced. It is written by Jeremy Gray: www.ams.org/notices/200009/rev-gray.pdf

Comment: You may be interested in contributing to a proposed Spanish language version of math stackexchange; it could use some input from fluent professors and students: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64529/matematicas-mathematics-se-in-spanish

Answer (score 3):

Since no other answer came up, I repeat my comment as an answer. The book written by [Charles Seife](http://www.zerothebook.com/): [Zero: The Biography of a Dangerous Idea](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140296476) which won the 2000 PEN/Martha Albrand Award for First Nonfiction. And you may find a review to the book (written by Jeremy Gray in Notices) [here](http://www.ams.org/notices/200009/rev-gray.pdf)  .

Answer (score 3):

There is also the little book by Robert Kaplan, [The Nothing that is: a Natural History of Zero](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195142373) (Oxford University Press, 2000).

Comment: This is a much better book than that by Seife. Another book to consider is Tobias Dantzig: Numbers: The language of science.

Answer (score 0):

Alain Schärlig, Du zéro à la virgule; Les chiffres arabes à la conquête de l'Europe, 1143–1585, Presses Polytechniques et Universitaires Romandes, Lausanne, 2010. 296 pp. ISBN: 978-2-88074-890-6. MR2741951

Rabindrnath Mukherjee, Discovery of zero and its impact on Indian mathematics, Das Gupta & Company Private Ltd., Calcutta, 1991. MR1314426

Georges Ifrah, From one to zero; A universal history of numbers, Penguin Books, New York, 1987. xvi+503 pp. ISBN: 0-14-009919-0.  MR0915160